# Why is nodal cubic the most general singular cubic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

On page 8 (right before Example(I.5.3)) of [this notes by Miranda](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Emiranda/BTES-Miranda.pdf),
it is stated that “nodal cubic is the most general singular cubic”, without further explanation.

Why is this the case?

Comment: The linked duplicate computes the dimension of the locus of each singularity type of plane cubics inside the space of plane cubics. One can see that the locus of nodal cubics has the largest dimension among singular cubics, therefore nodal cubics are the most general type of singular cubic.

Comment: Amazing, the link is precisely what I need. Thank you!!